# InvalidValueError no detectado: no es una matriz

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Tengo el siguiente código, el cual obtiene las coordenadas de una base de datos y crea los marker en un mapa, pero quiero "unir los markers" usando polylineas, pero que se hagan solos, de acuerdo al orden como se obtienen las coordenadas.
En el siguiente codigo solo se crean los markers en el mapa pero no las lineas

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
var locations = [],
    map,
    center = new google.maps.LatLng(locations),
    poly,
    ruta = Array();

function initialize() {
@foreach (RutaRastreo ruta in Model.RutaRastreo){
 if (ruta.Gps_Latitud != 0 && ruta.Gps_Longitud != 0){
 @:locations.push([@ruta.Gps_Latitud, @ruta.Gps_Longitud]);
 }
}
 
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     zoom: 10,
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(locations),
     });
     
     var marker,
         i,
         bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
ruta[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i], locations[i]);                                 

marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
map: map
});

bounds.extend(marker.position);
drawPath();

}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
}
 initialize();
 console.log(ruta);       
            
 function drawPath() {
  new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: ruta,
  geodesic: true,
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  strokeWeight: 4,
  map: map
   });
}
</script>
```

En la consola se muestran los resultados de hacer console.log(ruta);

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]